# What is the reward for the Bonus at the end of Act2?

Tags: diablo-iii

At the End of Act 2, right before the boss fight.

> There is an event where you must save the people from the city being attacked and lead them to the sewer.  They can die by being attacked or poison bombed

What is the bonus you receive if you complete this event perfectly?

I did it twice now and failed miserably

Comment: Did you check the achievements that are listed unter Act II?

Comment: No, but that is a good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you manage to rescue 20 people, you will receive the **[Hero of Caldeum](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/hero-of-caldeum)** achievement.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the gold each person drops outside the sewer, if you go inside the sewer there are treasure chests that are supposedly based on how well you did.

I've only completed the event once since someone told me of the chests inside, so only know the chests exist, and haven't verified if you get more/better ones if you do better at the event